# getting first index value from dropdown list

Tags: asp.net

I need to display the grid View populated with some data on selected index change event of a Drop Down List .

It will be fine when selecting other index values from the drop down list at first time.

but when selecting first index value at first time ,the selected value returns nothing.

how to get the selected value from the drop down list on first click.

Comment: Show some code you have already written/displaying

Comment: just call below code dropdown_selectedindexchanged(nothing,nothing)

Comment: Do you set a selected value / index when populating the combobox?

Answer (score 1):

Don't set `SelectedValue` or `SelectedIndex` while populating/binding the DropDownList.